# List Index out of range - Cant find out of range variables

Tags: python, indexing, range, out

I am having a error stating "List index out of range". I have looked everywhere in the code to find where a number could be called out of range of two set numbers. I apologies if I am on the wrong lines as I am quite new to this.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,time,geolocation,publisher
from subprocess import call

SleepTime = 10 # seconds
_lat = 0.00
_lon = 0.00

def maintain():
    global _lat
    global _lon
    (lat,lon,accuracy) = geolocation.getLocation()
    if(lat != _lat or lon !=_lon):
        data = str(lat) + "," + str(lon) + "," + str(accuracy)
        print ("publishing") , data
        publisher.publishtoInternet(data)
        _lat = lat
        _lon = lon
    else:
        print ("no change in coordinates")

print ("program begins")
while True:
    try:
        maintain()
    except Exception as inst:
        print (type)(inst), ('exception captured')
        print (inst)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        #file = open('/tmp/loctracker.error.log','a')
        #file.write('exception occured, trying to reboot')
        #file.close()
        #call(["sudo","reboot"])
    #break
    for i in range(0,SleepTime):
        sys.stdout.write ("restarting in %d seconds " % (SleepTime-i))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
```

The program is suppose to find the location from your network IP address and send the data to google maps which then sends back the location which is then sent to Sparkfish.com to store the data.

I changed the code with the below answers but still no luck. Here is the code and a screenshot.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,time,geolocation,publisher
from subprocess import call

SleepTime = 10 # seconds
_lat = 0.00
_lon = 0.00

def maintain():
global _lat
global _lon
(lat,lon) =geolocation.getLocation()
if(lat != _lat or lon != _lon):
    data = str(lat) + "," + str(lon) + "," + str(accuracy)
    print ("publishing") , data
    publisher.publishtoInternet(data)
    _lat = lat
    _lon = lon
else:
    print ("no change in coordinates")

print ("program begins")
while True:
try:
    maintain()
except Exception as inst:
    print (type)(inst), ('exception captured')
    print (inst)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    #file = open('/tmp/loctracker.error.log','a')
    #file.write('exception occured, trying to reboot')
    #file.close()
    #call(["sudo","reboot"])
#break
for i in range(0,SleepTime):
    sys.stdout.write ("restarting in %d seconds " % (SleepTime-i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Screen shot
  !(https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2BBD197F439CC237!30330&authkey=!AJv8LN5_4gHqKpI&ithint=file%2c)

Comment: What is this code supposed to be doing? Also your function maintain() isn't properly indented

Comment: The full traceback would be helpful.

Comment: The traceback message is **extremely** helpful in finding exact *where the error happened*.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a proper look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#responses
As it says,

```
geolocation.getLocation()
```

returns only two objects i.e. latitude and longitude.
You're trying to unpack the values in 3 variable tuple which is giving you the error! 
Try

```
(lat, lon) = geolocation.getLocation()
```

I'm not sure as to how you'll get accuracy and whether any method like

```
geolocation.getAccuracy()
```

exists or not for I have never used the module. Just interpreting it from the docs !

Comment: I tried the above things about the google Lat, Lon and Accuracy and so I removed the accuracy to try and match the JSON formating. However, I still get the same problem and errors. Anyone have any other ideas? :/

Thanks!

Comment: Then please edit and add a copy of the full traceback call which appears in your interpreter when you run the code. Only then we might get a clear idea of what's happening!

Comment: Here is the traceback. program begins
Logging in to router home page
<type 'exceptions.IndexError'> exception captured
list index out of range
restarting in 10 seconds restarting in 9 seconds restarting in 8 seconds restarting in 7 seconds restarting in 6 seconds restarting in 5 seconds restarting in 4 seconds restarting in 3 seconds restarting in 2 seconds restarting in 1 seconds

Comment: Extremely sorry sir, can't figure out the problem. It must somehow exist in getLocation() method though! There must be other apis available for location purpose, try something other than geolocation.Try `geopy` :).
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy

Comment: Unfortunately no luck! Guess il just have to give up this one haha

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the error is returned form your (lat,lon,accuracy) = geolocation.getLocation() look at the source below. your assignment doesn't match the json formating. the json formating has lon and lat as a sub field of location, and accuracy on it's own.

Geolocation responses

A successful geolocation request will return a JSON-formatted response defining a location and radius.

location: The user’s estimated latitude and longitude, in degrees. Contains one lat and one lng subfield.
accuracy: The accuracy of the estimated location, in meters. This represents the radius of a circle around the given location.
{
  "location": {
    "lat": 51.0,
    "lng": -0.1
  },
  "accuracy": 1200.4
}

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#wifi_access_point_object

Comment: I tried the above things about the google Lat, Lon and Accuracy and so I removed the accuracy to try and match the JSON formating. However, I still get the same problem and errors. Anyone have any other ideas? :/

Thanks!